# how to parse multiple values from variable list to test case

Tags: robotframework

I have different elements, each identified by text.

example:

```
//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/btn_number" and @text="1"]

//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/btn_number" and @text="2"]
```

i created
**resourse.txt** which @{KEYPAD} is the posibble values that user can choose at @text="varnumbers"

```
*** Variables ***
${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER}   ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/btn_number"]
@{KEYPAD}    1    2   3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0


#************* Login **************
Input SmartCard Pin
    [Arguments]    ${BUTTON}
    Tap            ${LOGIN-BUTTON-NUMBER}\[@text="@{KEYPAD}"]



*** Test Cases ***
Add Item
    Open Application
    Input SmartCard Pin          [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

**error on execution:**

```
ValueError: Element locator '//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="com.test.abc.work.cac:id/btn_number"][@text="['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']"]' did not match any elements.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Input SmartCard Pin
[Arguments]         ${PASSCODE}=${SMARTCARD-PIN}
@{KEYS}           Split String To Characters          ${PIN}
FOR     ${KEY}    IN      @{KEYS}
    Tap     ${ANDROID-WIDGET-TEXT-VIEW}\[@text="${KEY}"]
END
```

Comment: For the answer to be of help for other people visiting this Q&A site - please explain briefly what makes this work.

Comment: use case, user press 1, 2, 3, 4 . automation script one line code [1,2,3,4] then split it to fit each element @text, the end result sent 4 elements.